# Problem processing inbound emails to activities

Tags: email, cron-job

Using Civi 4.6.10 and Drupal 7, when running the scheduled job to process inbound emails I'm constantly seeing the following error:

```
Dec 31 13:39:53  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => No clue about the ezcMailDeliveryStatus
    [code] =>
)


Dec 31 13:39:53  [info] $backTrace = #0 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(322): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/Incoming.php(88): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("No clue about the ezcMailDeliveryStatus")
#2 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/Incoming.php(221): CRM_Utils_Mail_Incoming::formatMailPart(Object(ezcMailDeliveryStatus), (Array:0))
#3 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/Incoming.php(115): CRM_Utils_Mail_Incoming::formatMailMultipartReport(Object(ezcMailMultipartReport), (Array:0))
#4 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/Incoming.php(85): CRM_Utils_Mail_Incoming::formatMailMultipart(Object(ezcMailMultipartReport), (Array:0))
#5 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/Incoming.php(342): CRM_Utils_Mail_Incoming::formatMailPart(Object(ezcMailMultipartReport), (Array:0))
#6 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php(249): CRM_Utils_Mail_Incoming::parseMailingObject(Object(ezcMail))
#7 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail/EmailProcessor.php(111): CRM_Utils_Mail_EmailProcessor::_process(FALSE, Object(CRM_Core_DAO_MailSettings))
#8 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(386): CRM_Utils_Mail_EmailProcessor::processActivities()
#9 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_fetch_activities((Array:1))
#10 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(96): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9))
#11 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->run("Job", "fetch_activities", (Array:1), NULL)
#12 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(131): civicrm_api("Job", "fetch_activities", (Array:1))
#13 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(102): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob))
#14 /data/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/cron.php(53): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJobByAction("job", "fetch_activities")
#15 {main}
```

In researching this issue I've come across https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-9484 which looks to be generating the same error (although I'm not seeing empty contact records being created). I can see that that issue is fixed for 4.7., but I don't want to upgrade to 4.7 (it's in beta as I write, plus I want to stay with 4.6. as the nominated LTS version).
I also know that email to activity processing was working correctly a few months ago. Might this be due to problematic email messages in the mailbox being checked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it sounds like it's hitting an email it doesn't know how to parse - see the code for that function formatMailPart() where it fails (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/master/CRM/Utils/Mail/Incoming.php). Can you tell which email? Anything odd about it? In particular if you view the message source there might be a "Content-Type:" line with an unsupported type.

That "fix" for 4.7 all it does is just skips the email instead of a fatal error, but you'd still have an email that doesn't get processed.

Comment: I've since moved all the email messages out of the inbox and the scheduled job is now running correctly, confirming that there is an issue with one or more of the emails that are waiting to be processed. Skipping over these offending emails rather than throwing a fatal error sounds like a very positive step forward - I look forward to seeing that implemented in the 4.6.x series.

Comment: If you feel comfortable applying patches the one you linked to will probably work as-is for 4.6. Back up the file first just in case. (Direct link to patch: https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6748.diff)